# Issue with module's hook_uninstall (not uninstalling db entries)

Tags: 6, database, datetime

I have a [custom Drupal 6 module](https://gist.github.com/f7a161e8674c73607e86) ([based on this issue](http://drupal.org/node/911940#comment-5643314)) that puts some custom date and time formats into the `date_format_types` table and then can be accessed from `/admin/settings/date-time/formats`.  This works nicely but I'd like to remove these from that table if the module gets uninstalled.

In my module's .install file, I tried this code:

```
<?php

/**
 * Implementation of hook_uninstall().
 */
function eventdates_custom_uninstall() {
  db_query("DELETE FROM {date_format_types} WHERE type LIKE 'eventdates_custom_date_%'");
}
```

This does not seem to work and the entries that had been added do not get removed from the date_format_types table when I uninstall the module but I am pretty sure I have the query correct. [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%` is used as the placeholder marker for D6 queries, so you need to escape it with another `%`:

```
db_query("DELETE FROM {date_format_types} WHERE type LIKE 'eventdates_custom_date_%%'");
```

As a test I just added the following to the date_format_types table:

[image]

And then ran this query from the devel/php page:

```
db_query("DELETE FROM {date_format_types} WHERE type LIKE 'eventdates_custom_date_%%'");
```

And both rows were deleted:

[image]

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work, made sure to clear cache after I updated the code. Just as a test I did this in MySQL and it worked fine: `DELETE FROM `date_format_types` WHERE `type` LIKE 'eventdates_custom_date_%'` Not sure what else I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @DannyEnglander I've updated the answer with a successful test I just tried out. Can you try running similar code manually and see if it works. At least that will determine whether it's the query failing, or the program execution not getting into your `hook_uninstall()` function

Comment: Yes, that method worked so that means I am doing something wrong on my end with the way I have my module set up. I will have to troubleshoot that somehow. Thanks.

Comment: One interesting thing I just noticed, based on http://drupal.org/node/123825#comment-1125357 I also needed to go to `admin/build/modules/uninstall` and click uninstall for my module and then the data was removed from the table. That seems odd, why would you need to take that extra step?

Comment: Actually, this implies that's correct, the data only gets removed after you disable and "uninstall" the module. http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21install.php/function/hook_uninstall/6 So it seems like the method I am using will not be invoked when the module is simply disabled. I guess this makes sense in a lot of ways...

Comment: Ah yes that old chestnut...it's one of those things, once you know about it you never even think about it again you just do it. But until you do it can cause no end of problems. Drupal has a quite a few of those ;) Glad you got it sorted